# executing with Wine gives : vsprintf options 25 not handled

Tags: c++, printf, wine

While properly executing under windows or wine I have the following message when executing under Wine :
0009:fixme:msvcrt:MSVCRT__stdio_common_vsprintf options 25 not handled

Any Idea of where this could come from ?

Code is compiled with vs2019 and executed unde Wine Stable wine-4.0.2